# how to write the csv file in S3 using expresses NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

Can any one help on writing file CSV and then uploading using S3 Nodejs.

I was trying

```
fs.writeFileSync(path, data)
```

but it does not work for me

Please guide, a demo will help me a lot

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't upload the file directly,first you need to add AWS S3 API module to your project and use it. You can find a good example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html)